Installing Angular npm error code ECONNRESET npm error syscall read npm error errno -4077 npm error network read ECONNRESET
I am trying to install angular using npm. I installed Angular with no errors but when I do ng new test it creates the files but does not get past the installing stage. I am under a corporate network but not a proxy. I get an ECONNRESET error saying there was a problem with the network connectivity.
I have already tried all the npm install variations with --force, -g, npm update, npm i. No matter what I do it still gives this error. I have also tried using http and ssl-verify to be false. I have also used the certificate which I manually updated for npm which is what allowed me to use npm install at all, but I still cant fully make a new Angular application that will allow me to call ng serve. Using ng serve gives me "Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.". IT has already said that I have access to applications and should be able to use npm now. Any Ideas?

Please provide the error log formatted as code in the question, not in the title. The title should summarize what the problem is and how it is unique. See [ask] for more tips.

It sounds like node.js version issue
